# Have to reset resolution between each picture with PiCamera

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, picamera

I am using Picamera library in Python in combination ith the new HQ camera and I found that if I want to
use the image port and take pictures in a loop, I must set the resolution again and again in the loop. Is this normal behaviour? It seems stupid to have to set it over and over (I checked the call that setting the resolution makes and it's not a very fast one).

Here is the code I am using:

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera.camera import PiCamera

with PiCamera() as camera:
    with PiRGBArray(camera) as output:
        #camera.resolution = (1280, 720) #THIS DOES NOT WORK
        while not self._stop_camera_stream:
            camera.resolution = (1280, 720) #BUT THIS DOES
            camera.capture(output, 'rgb')
            print('Captured %dx%d image' % (output.array.shape[1], output.array.shape[0]))
            #The line beginning here are for a preview inside a PyQt5 Window
            image = output.array
            h, w, ch = image.shape
            bytesPerLine = ch*w
            convertedToQtFormat = QImage(image, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
            p = convertedToQtFormat.scaled(640,480,Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.changePixmap.emit(p)
            output.truncate(0)
```

Comment: did you try to set resolution before `PiRGBArray(camera)` ?

Comment: maybe ask on RPi forum: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/

Comment: or maybe read all in documetation [PiCamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/)

Comment: I've read the doc over and over in the past week and I found nothing that mentions this. I try will furas recommendation and I'll come back in a few hours max.

Comment: I just tried to set the resolution before the call to create the PiRGBArray but it does not work either. I also tried passing the camera resolution in the size parameter of PiRGBArray call but it didn't do anything different.